# Custom PostgreSQL aggregate for circular average

Tags: postgresql, types, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to implement a custom aggregate function in Postgres which will average directions in degrees - i.e. I want to able to do:

```
SELECT circavg(direction) FROM sometable;
```

This can be done using the formula:

```
xbar = atan2(sum(sin(xi), sum(cos(xi)))
```

I think I need to define an `sfunc` which will take a direction, and add the sine and cosine of that into two accumulators. The final function then converts the two components back into a direction using atan2.

I can't work out how to define the `sfunc` so that the current state consists of *two* components e.g. `(float, float)`. The documentation is a bit short on concrete examples, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Your described `circavg` is taking single parameter, while you've specified 2 parameters in `xbar` sample. Also, you miss closing parenthesis in your example.

Comment: @vyegorov: the xbar example does have only a single paramter (`xi`) It's used in two places though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of an **ARRAY** type internally. Argument type can still be any numeric type. Demonstrating with `float` (= `double precision`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_circavg (float[], float)
  RETURNS float[] LANGUAGE sql STRICT AS
'SELECT ARRAY[$1[1] + sin($2), $1[2] + cos($2), 1]';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_circavg_final (float[])
  RETURNS float  LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT CASE WHEN $1[3] > 0 THEN atan2($1[1], $1[2]) END';

CREATE AGGREGATE circavg (float) (
   sfunc     = f_circavg
 , stype     = float[]
 , finalfunc = f_circavg_final
 , initcond  = '{0,0,0}'
);
```

The transition function `f_circavg()` is defined `STRICT`, so it ignores rows with `NULL` input. It also sets a third array element to identify sets with one or more input rows - else the `CASE` the final function returns `NULL`.

Temporary table for testing:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (x float);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2), (NULL), (3), (4), (5);
```

I threw in a `NULL` value to also test the `STRICT` magic. Call:

```
SELECT circavg(x) FROM t;

       circavg
-------------------
 -2.78318530717959
```

Cross check:

```
SELECT atan2(sum(sin(x)), sum(cos(x))) FROM t;

       atan2
-------------------
 -2.78318530717959
```

Returns the same. Seems to work. In test with a bigger table the last expression with regular aggregate functions was 4x faster than the custom aggregate.

Test for zero input rows / only NULL input:

```
SELECT circavg(x) FROM t WHERE false;     -- no input rows
SELECT circavg(x) FROM t WHERE x IS NULL; -- only NULL input
```

Returns `NULL` in both cases.

Comment: It returns `0` if there's no rows. It should return `NULL` instead,

Comment: @user: I improved the custom aggregate function to work for no rows and / or NULL value input, too. (My favorite is the faster solution with regular aggregate functions.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have posted a related question. It'd be great if you can take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54829781/512251

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL provides you with a set of [geometry types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6432), `POINT` being the fundamental one.
Use this type as the input parameter for your function.

You can create your [custom type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtype.html) as an alternative if you prefer.