# Ordering distinct column values by (first value of) other column in aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to order the output order of some distinct aggregated text based on the value of another column with something like:

```
string_agg(DISTINCT sometext, ' ' ORDER BY numval)
```

However, that results in the error:

> ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list

I do understand why this is, since the ordering would be "ill-defined" if the `numval` of two repeated values differs, with that of another lying in-between.

Ideally, I would like to order them by first appearance / lowest order-by value, but the ill-defined cases are actually rare enough in my data (it's mostly sequentially repeated values that I want to get rid of with the `DISTINCT`) that I ultimately don't particularly care about their ordering and would be happy with something like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sometext ORDER BY numval SEPARATOR ' ')` that simply works despite its sloppiness.

I expect some Postgres contortionism will be necessary, but I don't really know what the most efficient/concise way of going about this would be.

Comment: Some sample data would be really nice here - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is part of a larger expression, it might be inconvenient to do a `select distinct` in a subquery.  In this case, you can take advantage of the fact that `string_agg()` ignores `NULL` input values and do something like:

```
select string_agg( (case when seqnum = 1 then sometext end) order by numval)
from (select sometext, row_number() over (partition by <whatever>, sometext order by numval) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by <whatever>
```

The subquery adds a column but does not require aggregating the data.

Comment: This would work, except that the `partition by` needs to include the original grouping columns (i.e. the `<whatever>`) before `sometext` for it to work as intended; otherwise every instance of `sometext` but the first one gets lost on the aggregate text.

Answer (score 7):

#### Building on `DISTINCT ON`

```sql
SELECT string_agg(sometext, ' ' ORDER BY numval) AS no_dupe
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (1,2) <whatever>, sometext, numval
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1,2,3
    ) sub;
```

This is the simpler equivalent of [@Gordon's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25181698/939860).
From your description alone I would have suggested [@Clodoaldo's simpler variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25181026/939860).

#### `uniq()` for integer

For `integer` values instead of `text`, the additional module [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) has **just the thing** for you:

```
uniq(int[])     int[]   remove adjacent duplicates
```

Install it once per database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

Then the query is simply:

```
SELECT uniq(array_agg(some_int ORDER BY <whatever>, numval)) AS no_dupe
FROM   tbl;
```

Result is an array, wrap it in [`array_to_string()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) if you need a string.
Related:

- [How to create an index for elements of an array in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867577/in-postgresql-how-do-you-create-an-index-by-each-element-of-an-array/10868144#10868144)
- [Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements/12870508#12870508)

In fact, it wouldn't be hard to create a custom aggregate function to do the same with `text` ...

### Custom aggregate function for any data type

Function that only adds next element to array if it is different from the previous. (`NULL` values are removed!):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_append_uniq (anyarray, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyarray
  LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT CASE WHEN $1[array_upper($1, 1)] = $2 THEN $1 ELSE $1 || $2 END';
```

Using [polymorphic types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14712776/939860) to make it work for *any* scalar data-type.
Custom aggregate function:

```sql
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_uniq(anyelement) (
   SFUNC = f_array_append_uniq
 , STYPE = anyarray
 , INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

Call:

```sql
SELECT array_to_string(
          array_agg_uniq(sometext ORDER BY <whatever>, numval)
        , ' ') AS no_dupe
FROM   tbl;
```

Note that the aggregate is `PARALLEL UNSAFE` (default) by nature, even though the transition function could be marked `PARALLEL SAFE`.

Related answer:

- [Custom PostgreSQL aggregate for circular average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225357/custom-postgresql-aggregate-for-circular-average/10226197#10226197)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with Postgres 13 (`PostgreSQL 13.0 (Debian 13.0-1.pgdg100+1)`); it just returns an empty array for all inputs. Ex: `select b, array_agg_uniq(a+c order by a+c) from generate_series(1, 10) a, generate_series(2, 5) b, generate_series(2, 5) c group by b;` although I actually intend to use it for strings. I think the problem is that `array_upper('{}', 1)` is null, which propagates through the `$1[idx]`. `SELECT CASE WHEN array_length($1, 1) <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN $1[array_upper($1, 1)] <> $2 THEN $1 || $2 ELSE $1 END ELSE ARRAY[$2] END` works, but doesn't seem great?

Comment: I *think* I got it to work with: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_append_uniq (anyarray, anyelement) RETURNS anyarray AS $func$ SELECT CASE WHEN $1[array_upper($1, 1)] = $2 THEN $1 ELSE $1 || $2 END $func$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE;` (swapping clauses of conditional, and adding `strict` to ignore null inputs.

Comment: @Shabble: Yes, both your changes are good. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 6):

Eliminate the need to do a distinct by pre aggregating

```
select string_agg(sometext, ' ' order by numval)
from (
    select sometext, min(numval) as numval
    from t
    group by sometext
) s
```

[@Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25181698/131874) brought a good point. That is if there are other needed columns. In this case a `distinct on` is recommended

```
select x, string_agg(sometext, ' ' order by numval)
from (
    select distinct on (sometext) *
    from t
    order by sometext, numval
) s
group by x
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really do what one would expect if `sometext` and `numval` together are not unique across the ungrouped rows, which is the case for me.

Comment: @Dologan Does not make sense to me. Can you post sample data and desired result?

Comment: Thank you for this, it really helped - SQL can be so fiddly sometimes

Answer (score 3):

What I've ended up doing is to avoid using `DISTINCT` altogether and instead opted to use regular expression substitution to remove sequentially repeated entries (which was my main goal) as follows:

```
regexp_replace(string_agg(sometext, ' ' ORDER BY numval), 
               '(\y\w+\y)(?:\s+\1)+', '\1', 'g')
```

This doesn't remove repeats if the external ordering leads to another entry coming in between them, but this works for me, probably even better. It may be a bit slower than other options, but I find it speedy enough for my purposes.

Comment: As it turns out, PostgreSQL versions earlier than 9.3.5 down to 9.2 at least have a memory leak on regular expressions including back-references (such as mine), and can gobble up a lot of memory for the lifetime of the session. This has [recently been fixed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-5.html)